# ErrorMessage with Range using Data annotations

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I have this:

```
    [Range(1, 1000, ErrorMessage = "Enter a value between 1 and 1000")]
    public object ObjectLimit { get; set; }
```

Works great, but it doesnt show the error message, it shows some standard "The value '554g' is not valid for the ObjectLimit field."

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a regular expression in this case, like:

```
 [RegularExpression(@"^[1-1000]{1,4}$", ErrorMessage = "RangeAllowed")]
 public object ObjectLimit { get; set; }
```

This will catch if you provide non integer values.

Answer (score 2):

Your setting a range of valid **integers**, 554g is not an integer.

Looks like you need a RegulagExpression attribute with the correct expression to match 554g as a correct value.

Comment: But if I use regular expression I cant add a range check too?

Comment: Well, yes, but its not that easy. http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Comment: I believe the OP was asking how to get the custom error message to show up. '554g' appears to be a test value to test the error message. I have the same question of how to make it use my own custom error message and not the default one, which is how ended up here.